# Indexing combinations of positions in an array without for-loop

Tags: r, indexing

I have a "look up array" h, where I want to look up certain parameter combinations. 
For reasons of computational time I do not want to loop through combinations with a for loop.

```
h[,,1]
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

h[,,2]
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18

...
```

i now want combinations like

```
h[3,2,1]
h[2,2,2]
h[3,1,1]
```

written as

```
a<-c(3,2,39
b<-c(2,2,1)
c<-c(1,2,1)
h[a,b,c]
```

and the result should be a vector:

> 6  14  2

Needless to say this does not work, instead R gives me all possible combinations of parameters.

to recreate the expample use

```
h<-array(1:(3*3*5),dim=c(3,3,5))
```

or

```
structure(1:45, .Dim = c(3L, 3L, 5L))
```

Comment: Done. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to do it, by converting a, b, and c into a matrix usind cbind()
and then simply indexing

```
h[cbind(a,b,c)]
```